# extends PubsubIO.Read deduplicate window

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#using-record-ids

"If you've set a record ID label when using PubsubIO.Read, when Dataflow receives multiple messages with the same ID (which will be read from the attribute with the name of the string you passed to idLabel), Dataflow will discard all but one of the messages. However, Dataflow does not perform this de-duplication for messages with the same record ID value that are published to Pub/Sub more than 10 minutes apart."

it looks like the default deduplicate window is 10 min.
Is there some way to change the default dedup window, say 20 min?

Comment: I think not. I think it's a built in feature in the platform and you can't change this behavior. The other solution is to have windows of 20 minutes and to deduplicate message in the windows during the dataflow pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

@guillaume blaquiere is correct. The deduplicate window is fixed to 10 minutes as of now. If you want you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) and describe the nature of the request. When creating a feature request, make sure you click on the "Star". When the stars accumulate it can possibly bump the priority of the request.

Just to add on @guillaume blaquiere suggestion, you can use the [Distinct transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/distinct/) in your windows of 20 minutes in your pipeline.